Ensuring correct data input TidyCal to Zapier
We are using https://tidycal.com/ as our online booking calendar. The calendar comes with a form of pre-selected questions. However, it seems that TidyCal is handling this data in the order in which questions are answered - rather than each field having its own ID.
Currently, it seems that TidyCal identifies data in the order that answers are input by a user. For example; 'Question Answer 1' may be phone number on one form and it could be applicant name on another form, depending on which order the user has input the information.
This causes issues in Zapier as there's no way to call a specific field and ensure it is in the correct place each time as there is no constant I can call upon.
Fields are simply named "Question 1" "Question Answer 1" etc - but as behaviour fluctuates from user to user these field names are not always reliable.
I was wondering if there’s a way I can map these fields in Zapier so the correct field and data is called each time, regardless of which order the information is input.
Fairly inexperienced with API and hefty coding but willing to give any possible solution a go! THANKS IN ADVANCE
I have re-ordered my questions to try and navigate around auto-correct filling in fields ahead of time. This seemed to work but user behaviour is still unpredictable.
I attempted to call on the specific fields in Zapier but with generic names like "Question Answer 1" - which (depending on how the user inputs) may not actually be the answer to question 1, I am struggling to find a constant to call upon.
